# Resolving cloud storage permissions of service account used by Kubernetes CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, kubernetes-cronjob

I have this Kubernetes Cronjob that is supposed to backup and upload the file to my cloud storage bucket.

As you can see in the args, I get my database password from my secrets in the first line, then I am passing it to and executing a database backup script living in my database pod. Then I get the name of the file created, and use the kubectl cp command to copy it from inside the pod to the filesystem of the cronjob.

I have inserted an ls after that command and checked that the backup successfully gets copied into the cronjob pod.

Additionally, the gsutil ls does print the buckets available, meaning the service account can use the gsutil cli.

However when it gets to the gsutil cp line, the logs show that I am hit with an access denied message with a 403 error, even though I have given the service account used by the cronjob storage admin and storage object admin. I check my bucket and it is still empty How should I proceed from here? Are there any additional configurations I may have missed?

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: database-backup
  namespace: dev
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: database-backup
              image: google/cloud-sdk:latest
              command: [ "sh", "-c" ]
              args:
                - |
                  DB_PWD=$(kubectl get secret database-secret -o jsonpath="{.data.password}" | base64 --decode)
                  kubectl exec -i database-0 /bin/bash -- ./backup_database.sh $DB_PWD
                  BACKUP_FILE=$(kubectl exec database-0 -- find / -name "backup-*" -type f 2>/dev/null | cut -c 2-)
                  kubectl cp database-0:$BACKUP_FILE backup
                  ls
                  gsutil ls
                  gsutil -D cp backup gs://my-bucket
                  rm -f backup
                  kubectl exec -i database-0 -- rm -f $BACKUP_FILE

          restartPolicy: OnFailure
---
# cluster role stuff
```

Comment: I would not use `kubectl exec` here.  Put the backup script and install the database client tools in the image the CronJob runs, and point it at your database's Service.  I'd guess all of your `kubectl` calls are failing for lack of permissions, but you should be able to see that in the logs of your pod.

Comment: @DavidMaze my kubectl calls work, what is failing only is the gsutil cp command only.